# add border-radius on column group css

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, html-table

In the HTML table, I am trying to apply border-radius on the column group but it is not working. Is there any way to fix this?

I have to implement accessibility on table view due to which I couldn't opt for other alternative solutions.

How can I apply the border-radius on the column group?

```css
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 30px;
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
}

colgroup > col.selected{
  border: 1.5px solid #2698d6;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 31px rgba(96, 96, 96, 0.1);
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
      <col span="1" class="selected" />
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
    <td>Column 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
    <td>Column 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
    <td>Column 4</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
    <td>Column 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: border radius for column ?

Comment: @MAYURSANCHETI  Yes. I have a requirement to implement it in such a way that when a user selects the column then border with border-radius should be added to it

Answer (score -1):

you can apply for td like below,

```css
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0 16px;
}

tr td {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  transition: all ease 0.3s;
  padding: 5px;
}

td {
  border-radius: 10px;

}

td:hover
{
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<body>
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>01</td>
    <td>02</td>
    <td>03</td>
    <td>04</td>
    <td>05</td>
    <td>06</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>07</td>
    <td>08</td>
    <td>09</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

please comment if any query

Comment: You have applied it on row. I want the border-radius to be on the column.

Comment: now check again

Comment: Not on individual column. Could you run the snippet code which I added as I have mentioned it as column-group.